# FitNesse: how to setup for .NET for all tests/suites?

Tags: fitnesse

I try to use Fitnesse with .NET. So, I have this setup on my test pages:

```
!define TEST_SYSTEM {slim}
!define COMMAND_PATTERN {%m -a ..\Orders.Tests\bin\Debug\Orders.Tests.config -r fitSharp.Slim.Service.Runner,slim\fitsharp.dll %p}
!define TEST_RUNNER {slim\Runner.exe}
!path ..\Orders.Tests\bin\Debug\Orders.Tests.dll

|import|
|Tests.Orders.Fit|
```

How do I make this to be used from single location? I tried to define this in PageHeader, suite's SetUp, and !include page, but in all cases, when I run test, it just hangs. If includes are directly on the test page, it runs fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, found that I can put everything on the root page... except import which do not work from there.

And |import| works from the Suite SetUp page. Actually all of the settings work. Don't know what was wrong, I think I tried to put it to the Suite SetUp...

Answer (score 3):

All the !defines and the !paths can go on a *parent* page of the test pages.  !defines and !paths are *inherited* into all child pages.

The |import| can go on a SetUp page.  SetUp pages are brothers, uncles, or [great*]uncles of the test pages.

So given a page structure like this:

```
ProjectPage
  SetUp
  FeaturePage
    MyFeature1
    MyFeature2
```

You can put the !path and !define statement into ProjectPage and the |import| into SetUp.